# Removing "catergories" string from function

Tags: php, wordpress, function

How can I remove the "category" string from this function.

```
function display_category_list($atts) {
  return wp_list_categories(array('echo' => false));
}
add_shortcode('display-categories', 'display_category_list');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [developer wordpress](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/#parameters)
See `title_li` parameter.

> 'title_li' (string) Text to use for the list title `<li>` element. Pass
>   an empty string to disable. Default 'Categories'.

for hiding title change your code to

```
function display_category_list($atts) {
  return wp_list_categories(array(
    'echo' => false,
    'title_li' => '',
  ));
}
add_shortcode('display-categories', 'display_category_list');
```

Comment: Thanks @Maxim If I wanted to rap the output with a span where would I need to add the element into the php?